# In ExtJS, How to inject enableKeyEvents = true in component?

Tags: events, extjs

This is my code,

```
myText.enableKeyEvents = true; // **
myText.on('keyup', function(t){ console.log(t.getValue()); });
```

It not work, I think it may has some invoke method.
Any one has an idea ?

---

**Full code**

```
// function
var txfJump = function(txf){
    var next = txf.nextSibling();
    if(next.xtype == 'textfield'){
        txf.enableKeyEvents = true;
        txf.on('keyup', function(t, e){
            if(t.getValue().length == t.maxLength){
                next.focus();
            }
        });
        txfJump(next);
    }
};
// form
var p = new Ext.Panel({
    title   : 'test panel',
    width   : 400,
    defaults: {
        xtype : 'textfield',
    },
    items   : [
        { ref : 'one',  maxLength : 5 },
        { ref : 'two',  maxLength : 5 },
        { ref : 'three',maxLength : 5 },
        {
            xtype   : 'button',
            text    : 'SAMPLE'
        },
        { ref : 'four', maxLength : 5 },
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
    txfJump(p.one);
});
```

Comment: Can you give a little more context for you code please? Paste the rest of your text field code and its container. You can omit other fields if you think their inclusion isn't necessary.

Comment: I update my full code, Thanks for response.

Comment: Now I found some action to enableKeyEvent, this is mom().  this is my code => txf.mon(txf.el, { scope : txf, keyup : txf.onKeyUp });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's not possible without hackish tricks**. Having read the `TextField`'s source, i found out, that there is a private method `initEvents`, that sets up the callbacks for the html-elements *if and only if* `enableKeyEvents` is set. So, changing `enableKeyEvents` after `initEvents` was called has no effect, until it is called again.

To inject it, one could try to trigger a re-rendering of the component, or one could copy the behaviour of the relevant parts of `TextField`'s `initEvent`. But there doesn't seem to be an official way.

Comment: Thanks keppla, Seem mon is called by that method.

Answer (score 2):

you have to call `txf.initEvents()`, this needs to be called after `txf.enableKeyEvents = true`;

```
var txfJump = function(txf){
var next = txf.nextSibling();
if(next.xtype == 'textfield'){
    txf.enableKeyEvents = true;
    txf.initEvents();            //<----- this is what you have missing
    txf.on('keyup', function(t, e){
        if(t.getValue().length == t.maxLength){
            next.focus();
        }
    });
    txfJump(next);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass "enableKeyEvents": true when getting new Ext.form.TextField instance. Here is the example usage

```
var textField = new Ext.form.TextField({
    . // your configs
    .
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    .
    .
})
```

Comment: I know that Fatih, But I want to do inject function, so I couldn't set component configuration.